# *.min.js not regenerated when ts updated

Tags: typescript

I have tracked down an issue in VS2012/Typescript.  It appears to me looking at the datetimes on some of the generated *.min.js files that some are not always being regenerated when the corresponding ts file is updated.

Has anyone else encountered a similar issue?

Comment: TypeScript does not generate .min.js files. Are you using some other plug-in?

Comment: webessentials 2012 has not given me this error

Comment: @rc I'm using the latest,ie June, typescript vs2012 plugin.  I suspect silent failure during code generation or some kind of dependency tree failure.  When I force regeneration of all code everything gets built.

Answer (score 1):

typescript won't generate min i think you can make use of the node project which is in beta in vs2013 update 3 i suppose and in there use node modules like gulp or grunt